# Empty columns on 12 column grid

Tags: css, width

I am working with the 12 column grid style sheet from http://cssgrid.net/

It's great, the only problem is that I cannot have empty columns on the left side of the page. If I create an empty div with class "threecol" for example, the contentless div is not being displayed.

```
.row .threecol {
width: 22.05%;
}
```

Here is the [whole CSS file](http://cssgrid.net/css/1140.css).

My question: Is there a way to add a class to empty columns that prevents them from being ignored, so I actually have an empty div with the given %-width?

Comment: This may not be a CSS issue as much as a content issue. You may want to populate your "empty" div with a proper `&nbsp;` entity just to make sure that it is not actually empty.

Comment: The problem is that I let the user decide himself if he wants to add content to that column or not. If he decides not to, it shouldn't break the layout. I could of course add the &nbsp; dynamically, but a css solution would be easier (for me) if there was one.

Comment: I understand, but the point I'm making is that this is a browser rendering issue (if my thinking is right about it). Some browsers simply will not render the div if it is truly empty. However, by detecting an empty div and injecting the non-breaking space entity this behavior may go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll either have to make the div "not empty" with something like a `&nbsp`, or to explicitly set a height (or min-height) value on it. As your div is empty, setting its height should probably not affect your layout anyway.